# Setting up a panel-header with a progress bar that runs the length of it

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a series of panels that correspond to a certain # of tasks that a user has to perform.

I set this up using panels where the panel heading has the Activity Name and when that is expanded, it reveals the list of tasks associated with that activity.  Each of teh tasks can have the status of incomplete, successful, failed.

I'd like to add a stacked progress bar to the heading so that, when the panel is collapsed, you can quickly see the status of the internal tasks.  Ideally the first row of the heading would be the activity name and the second row would be filled with the stacked progress bar.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h6>
                <a ng-click="erVM.showER = !erVM.showER">ER Heading goes here</a>
            </h6>
        </div>           
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="progress" style="width:100%">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:40%">
                    Free Space
                </div>
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:10%">
                    Warning
                </div>
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">
                    Danger
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This comes nowhere close to doing what I need it to do but it seems to follow the bootstrap requirements to implement what I'm saying.

ANy help would be greatly appreciated.